# Rails assets pipeline images with relative path arent loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm confused about how works assets pipeline, im using a gem called aloha-rails and it have the next CSS rule:

```
button.aloha-button {
    background: url("../img/base.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
}
```

If I run it on local, that rule is on file:

```
http://local.dev/assets/aloha/css/aloha.css?body=1
```

And I CAN see the image, it is loaded from this address:

```
http://local.dev/assets/aloha/img/base.png
```

But when I run it on heroku, on when I precompile assets on local the css rule is loaded from applications.css, the rule still with ../img/base.png so the image is trying to be loaded from:

```
http://server.herokuapp.com/img/base.png
```

and that DOESNT exist, so I receive a 404 error and dont see the image.

Answer (score 0):

Write as following:
 Remove the `dots(..)` before the path.

```
button.aloha-button {
 background: url("/img/base.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
}
```

Please do let me know if not working still.

Comment: But its a external gem.. do I have to fork it just to make this fix? I'm new to rails so im very confused, but im trying to do the things well. Assets pipeline cant work with relative paths?

also, /img/base.png doesnt exist, i think i should change that to /assets/aloha/img/base.png I'm right?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your image assets in production, where asset precompilation will stick a hash at the end of each filename, you need to use the `img-url` helper provided by sass-rails if your css has a .scss or .sass extension, or you can use the `asset_path` helper if you add .erb to the end of your stylesheet filenames:

```
button.aloha-button {
    background: image-url("/img/base.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
}
```

It seems like the aloha-rails gem doesn't do this. Probably also needs to drop the `..` in front of the path.

Comment: But that makes no sense, is insane. I mean, its an EXTERNAL library, and this library in particular have plugins, each plugin have CSS and as are plugins its common that use relative paths.

So I need to edit each css of each plugin just to make this work? its not possible to enable assets pipeline just for my libraries and not for external gems or vendors?. It's just common sense. Also those files are .css not .scass nor .sass.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa It's definitely frustrating in this case but it's not really that insane. It's aloha-**rails** after all, the whole point of this gem is to make aloha editor work with the asset pipeline. The gem's readme file says `The aloha-rails gem integrates the AlohaEditor editor with the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline.`

Comment: @ArnoldRoa This gem seems pretty broken and unmaintained anyway, last commit was 8 months ago and following the instructions in the README gives me an error with a brand new rails app. You probably want to look for another solution, or fix this one yourself :/

Comment: Woops turns out there's aloha-rails and locomotive-aloha-rails, in any case, neither of them works with the asset pipeline.